# OpenGL shaders run in parallel

Tags: opengl, gpgpu

In CUDA, kernels are run parallel in threads and blocks. Is it correct to think of OpenGL shaders as CUDA kernels? Is there any index for each shaders thread? How many shaders are run at the same time in parallel?

I'm implementing a GPGPU program in OpenGL.

Comment: No, OpenGL Compute Shaders maybe (workgroup size is a parameter). But the other kinds of shaders (Vertex, Fragment, Geometry, Tessellation Control / Evaluation) do not tell you how many are running in parallel or anything like that.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman You are right! but still we can think of shaders as parallel kernels running together. We just do not have access to define how many blocks of how many threads to run and how to fill the shared memory. Remember the time when people were using OpenGL shaders for GPGPU. The GPU Gems 2 book is full of such examples.